# 'CultureInfo' & 'NumberStyles' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo

when I was writing a basic C# program, I came across the following bugs. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoxgW.jpg)
I searched online and tried to add references in Solution Explorer but couldn't add any reference?
NumberStyles should be in Systems.Globalization.

Comment: Both of those class references are part of `System.Globalization'  (not `Systems.Globalization')  -- make sure you have a reference to this assembly to your project.

Comment: Welcome aboard, please provide more information about your project like the Framework (.NET Core or .Net Framework), the version, the project template. and please provide the code as text so can be tested. That will help us to help you.

Comment: Did you add this using statement ? `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: When you find these *missing reference* notifications, just press `ALT+ENTER` (with the caret inside an underlined keyword), Visual Studio will show a list of assemblies/namespaces/NuGet Packages that *may* contain the missing reference. It usually gets it right. The *light bulb* on left hand can do the same.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini I was using .NET Core.